# I need help to solve t test exercise 3.4 page 80 of Statistics for Experimenters by Box and Hunter second edition

Tags: t-test

**Exercise 3.4.** Given the following data from a randomized experiment, construct the randomization reference distribution and the approximate scaled *t* distribution. What is the significance level in each case?

Data 
  A, B, B, A, B,
3, 5, 5, 1, 8,

Answer, 0.05 , 0.04 as shown in the book

I tried and got {Pr(t >=2.68)= 0.037} which can be approximated to be **0.04**, but, I don't know how to construct randomization reference distribution. I also, know I should use {5!/(3!2!) = 10} but I can't imagine how to use this to construct randomization reference distribution. Where I am self studying statistics & DOE.

Ps; you may consider A, as method A, and B, as Method B.

Comment: Some thoughts: Can you say what hypothesis you are testing? I see how you got $T = 2.6833$ for a pooled t statistic, but 0.037 seems to be for a one-sided test (about which you say nothing). And can you define 'randomization reference distribution'? I do see that $\frac{1}{2{5 \choose 2}} = 0.05,$ but can you explain how or why that might be relevant?

Comment: It is one sided t test, $H_a: \mu_B>\mu_A$ , but I don't understand the basis of of getting 0.05.